# Why isn't this answer considered "link only" answer?

Tags: discussion, link-only-answers, declined-flags

A while ago I stumbled upon [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/872699/1714410):

> [Debugging and optimization of multi-thread OpenMP-programs](http://www.viva64.com/art-3-2-86765651.html)
>
> [OpenMP links collection](http://www.viva64.com/links/parallel-programming/)

I find it to be a link-only answer and I flagged it as such, as suggested by several meta discussions (e.g. [this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92505/should-i-flag-answers-which-contain-only-a-link-as-not-an-answer)).

However, my flag was declined with the following comment: "declined - flags should only be used to make moderators aware of content that requires their intervention".

WHY???

Comment: Related: [Your answer is in another castle: when is an answer not an answer?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225370)

Comment: moderator who declined totally screwed up: this doesn't even attempt to answer the question asked "I wonder if there is a flaw in the code that is causing some resource conflict, or if it is simply that..."

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260752/3315914

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It was flagged on March 13th, a minute before the comment was left to expand the answer.  The moderator in question *probably* declined it because there was no reason to involve moderators *at that point*.  As we've said before, [engage with users before asking us to nuke their answers from orbit](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/183603/can-we-get-some-consensus-on-what-flag-to-use-for-link-only-answers/183676#183676).

Another way to handle this would have been to downvote the answer ("it is not helpful or useful"), and then once it gets below zero votes, the community can delete it themselves -- there was no need to involve a moderator.

Comment: Yet there is no user there anymore to engage.

Comment: Surely the "not an answer" review queue is another outlet for these flags? i.e. it's not _just_ moderators involved. Why should we avoid using the system properly just so we don't possibly disturb moderators?

Comment: "if link has worth, edit. if not downvote." is that essentially it?

Answer (score 2):

I imagine it was dismissed because it is a very old answer (May 16 '09) back when SO was still a baby.

This coupled with the fact that the user no longer exists means that we can't ask the user to fix it and deleting it would remove valuable information from the site.

Of course, you could edit it yourself to improve the answer to make it SO-worthy by todays standards.

If the post doesn't answer the question with the links then this is a separate issue which has nothing to do with the length of the answer (a fully cited essay which doesn't answer the question still doesn't answer the question) which can be addressed with the down-vote button.