# Failed audit on what looked like a link-only answer—was I wrong in my judgement?

Tags: discussion, disputed-review-audits, link-only-answers

While reviewing low-quality posts, I was presented with [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24162427/3315914):

[image]

It looked to me like a link-only answer, so I flagged it as such. However, it was an audit and I didn't pass.

Why is this answer is considered a ***Good Answer***? I always thought that this type of answer was not appropriate for Stack Overflow.

EDIT: And why [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20551902/how-can-i-check-two-strings-for-similarity-in-php/20551966#20551966) is not considered a good answer?

Comment: @SLBarth why did you delete your answer?

Comment: @Shai The last paragraph in Cody Gray's answer addresses that. Although technically "use [strcmp] to compare strings" is correct, it is a symptom of a bad question.

Comment: So, you still have this window on your screen, waiting for you to click on "I understand" ; ).

Comment: @Teemu I changed it with chrome's developer tools to _I don't understand but I can't do anything about it_.

Comment: There is a long range in difference between "good answer", "ok answer", "bad answer" and "deleteworthy answer". imho that answer is not far away from deleteworthy, and it really depends on the context whether it oversteps the border. Mentally remove the link and any fluff, and then judge its deleteworthyness again. If nothing is left after that, it is surely deleteworthy. In this case, the text would probably stand as-is and would only be a rather bad answer.

Comment: The opinions seem to be split on this. See this Meta question which is official policy: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer.

Comment: Ah, question deleted!  So many (hungry) folks deprived of internet dollars.

Comment: @devnull I dont get that. What do you mean?

Comment: @PatrickHofman great post. Thanks for sharing

Comment: I think the answer is NOT bad but it has nothing at all to do with it appearing to be a link-only answer. The question is marginal on delete-mash; however the answer is of similar quality to the question. Perhaps an easy early clue the question is not so good is not a bad thing.

Comment: I actually ran into an opposite problem - I failed an audit when I approved a short answer that was primarily (but not solely) a link to an alternative to a deprecated piece of software, in a question about the deprecated software. The answer gave the rationale for switching and a link to the replacement.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

It is *not* a good answer. Downvoting is appropriate, perhaps even suggesting deletion.

However, the review system is not perfect. That answer stands with +6/-0 votes, and therefore *looks* to the system like a good answer. A false positive, in other words. You win some, you lose some. Take the blow to the ego in stride, then return outside of the review queue and give the answer the treatment you normally would. You won't be banned from reviewing just for failing one audit.

As for why that answer has earned 6 upvotes, the most likely explanation is that it is to a poor-quality question that has since been closed as "unclear". It was simple enough that even morons could understand it, so they mashed the upvote button, not realizing that the "close" button was a more appropriate target. This is a case study in why we close questions like this: they attract answers like this and people are inclined to upvote them.

You *could* argue that even if the link were removed, the answer would still be useful because it contains the name of a function. But you aren't going to get much mileage out of that. It just proves that the primary problem with the answer is not that it is "link only" but that it contains "insufficient detail", is "not clear or useful". Again, a symptom of a bad question that shouldn't have been answered.

Comment: I tend to agree with [S. L. Barth](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260753/1714410) - this is not a bad answer. It's short, but not bad.

Comment: I disagree with this idea that link only answers aren't good. Cluttering up StackExchange with what could be vast amounts of data, that could be in a constant state of flux, is much worse, and not what was asked for in many of these cases.

Comment: @ouflak the main problem with link only answers is that if the linked content is deleted or moved the answer is now useless. It's OK to link to additional information so long as the answer itself provides enough information to answer the question. If that requires *vasts amounts of data* then the question is probably to broad.

Comment: @Jack,The main problem with posting hoards of information instead of just posting a link is that it can easily clutter the site, and that information itself may be in a state of flux, in which case you still have the same problem as dying links, only with a lot more clutter. StackExchange cannot be, no should it ever be, considered a repository for all of the information on the internet. In a Q&A site where the question is asking for just the current link to the appropriate information, an answer containing just that link is absolutely correct.

Comment: @ouflak Like I mentioned If your posting hoards of information then perhaps the question should be closed as *too broad*. Aside from that in general questions just asking to find a off site resource are also considered off topic. At the very least the answer should contain a summary of the linked content in case the link does die.

Comment: @Jack, if you are posting hoards of information, instead of just posting a link, especially when that is all that was asked for, then something has gone very wrong. I think we can agree there. But we shouldn't just look at this from a StackOverflow perspective. There are plenty of sites where asking for just links to hard-to-find or otherwise obscure information is perfectly fine. One site I'm somewhat active on where this is the case is Theoretical Computer Science, where it is considered perfectly on-topic to ask for links to research papers that might not ever show up in any search engine.

Comment: There are also copyright considerations. It is one thing to post a link to a website that answers a question. But posting a copy-paste of somebody's website might violate certain copyright agreements, even if credit is given, and could be considered plagiarism if proper credit isn't given. I don't know where this idea that link-only answers are somehow inappropriate came from, but it certainly does not apply in many cases.

Comment: @ouflak Actually now that there is a [meta.stackexchange](http://meta.stackexchange.com/) site here on MO we should be looking at it from StackOverflow... That said I would say that if your only going to post a link then perhaps consider leaving it as a comment.

Comment: If it's a good comment that answers the question, that's fine. If it's a good answer that answer that answers the question, that's also fine. I'm fine with either.

Comment: Regarding where the idea came from, it's been brought up numerous times both here on [MO](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=link+only) and on [ME](http://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=link+only) (though those were probably mostly migrated). I seem to recall that there were also some *official* answers (that is answers by SE employees) about this, but I'm not finding them right now.

Comment: In the [how to answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) section of the help center it says *"Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline."*.

Comment: And what does the help section say if the 'most relevant part' of the information that's been posted becomes obsolete, becomes otherwise inapplicable, or was wrong in the first place and has since had an update?

Comment: I disagree that it's not a bad answer. It's a pretty bad answer, but I would agree that it's not a delete-worthy answer. A delete-worthy answer would just say "read this link to learn how to compare two strings". If it just said "use strcmp to compare two strings", with no link, it would be exactly as crappy an answer, and I still wouldn't flag it as delete-worthy, it'd just be crappy.

Comment: @ouflak If the correct answer to a question changes frequently, and there's an external page that someone has committed to keep around and update whenever the answer changes, then say *that*, and link to the external page. It would look something like this: "You have to recalibrate it. Unfortunately, the way you do that changes every damn time they update the software. [Here is a link to the manufacturer's recalibration instructions, which are updated in step with the software]. There's a menu on that page that allows you to select which version you have." My understanding is that's enough.

Comment: I would add that "how do I compare strings in C?" is *not* a question whose answer changes frequently.

Comment: Hey everyone, if you have something to contribute or an argument to make against my answer, **post an answer**. My inbox is blowing up, and I can't even find the objections to respond to if I wanted to.

Answer (score 19):

I think this may be a case of overzealous reviewing that seems to be on the increase recently (possibly a consequence of actual increase in rubbish indeed, to put this into context).

---

The [first answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24162427/3315914) you mention is an answer to this question:

> **A function to compare two sentences in C**
>
> I am a beginner in programming. I have a problem in C which I can't
>   solve. I can't write a function which will print the result of
>   comparison of two sentences which are entered in program with fgets()
>   function. The program should print whether or not the entered
>   sentences are the same. WIll you ehlp me?

And the answer (now deleted) was:

> Use [strcmp](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcmp/) to compare two strings.

Firstly, let's address the question. It was initially closed as "*closed as unclear what you're asking*" (last week) and deleted today.

Admittedly, it's not the best question around, not necessarily the most researched either, but it could be salvaged quite easily (by first removing unnecessary text like "*WIll you ehlp me?*", which indeed makes it a low-quality question.)

If we're trying to build SO as a repository of knowledge, having questions about comparing two strings in C seems reasonable. If we're answering questions more generally to help, we can also provide a reasonable answer.

I wasn't involved in any voting in this Q&A, but I'd have look for a duplicate (like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23020391/372643)). Surely, this must have been asked before. If there wasn't a duplicate, "*unclear what you're asking*" doesn't seem like the right close reason (I think it's fairly clear).

Assuming the question isn't bad (which is arguable indeed here), **this would be a good criterion to evaluate whether it's a bad, link-only, delete-worthy answer: would this answer still be useful without any internet connection (or with that link being dead).**

The answer is yes. It's quite easy to run `man strcmp` locally on a Linux machine, for example. Those who consider it a link-only answer probably wouldn't have flagged it up had there not been a link under `strcmp` at all. It's not a great answer, but it's certainly correct and points the reader in the right direction. (A much better answer would have come with a short example perhaps.) Unhappy people can still downvote, that's what it's for.

Overall, it's probably best to keep it deleted, because of existing duplicates for this question.

---

The [second answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20551966/372643) you mention is very similar:

> You could use the `strcmp` function: [strcmp](http://www.php.net/strcmp)

Someone put a comment under it saying:

> While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

I'm afraid this is *not* a link-only answer. If anything, it *does* include the essential part of the answer: the name of the function to look for in the documentation.

(In this case, however, I definitely wouldn't have upvoted this answer (and I might have downvoted it), since it seems to miss the point of the question, by offering a solution that seems too simplistic for the general problem (although it would work in basic cases).)

I know I tend to write relatively long answers with details, but it must be said that short answers that go straight to the point (or at least that give the main information requested in the question) have their use. The first case you mention would fit this case (again, provided the question isn't an exact duplicate).

Comment: +1 for some reason people on this site seem allergic to 1-line answers.

Comment: The second answer is still rather poor.  In many cases, knowing the name of the function is not good enough, you have to know how to use it as well.  Look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21608987/1652962).  Going through the documentation is not going to help you here (and I'm not the only person who didn't get it, note that the OP didn't accept it as the answer even though it came from one of the maintainers of the library in question).

Comment: @cimmanon, these may be poor answers, but they are answers that provide some information that can be useful nonetheless. Knowing where to look and what to look for are often helpful, even if these are just partial answers. If you find one of these isn't sufficiently helpful, don't upvote it, or possibly downvote it if you think it's misleading. Flagging it up for deletion is a different thing (especially flagging it up as "link-only", which it isn't).